# Get specific element in URL in sql server split

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a URL like - "hbc/420021/GATE (RBD-1)/Construction/D5200 Tutorial.pdf" 
And I have to create a function which will return a specific element in sql server.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by *a specific element*?  Do you want a part by name, then nth element in sequence, what?

Comment: I need the 3rd element to be specific. My function should return "GATE (RBD-1)".

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your question is actually a lot more complex than what you have included, but to answer it as is you just need to find the second and third `/` character and then return what is in-between.

I have spread the functions out a bit to make it easier to see where everything fits together:

```
declare @url nvarchar(500) = 'hbc/420021/GATE (RBD-1)/Construction/D5200 Tutorial.pdf';

select left(right(@url
                 ,len(@url) - charindex('/'
                                       ,@url
                                       ,charindex('/'
                                                 ,@url
                                                 ,0
                                                 )+1
                                       )
                 )
            ,charindex('/'
                      ,right(@url
                            ,len(@url) - charindex('/'
                                                  ,@url
                                                  ,charindex('/'
                                                            ,@url
                                                            ,0
                                                            )+1
                                                  )
                            )
                      ,0
                      )-1
            ) as ThirdElement;
```

Output:

`````````````
ThirdElement
````````````
GATE (RBD-1)
`````````````